What does the red dotted line on the p4v file version interface mean?
I don’t know what the function of the continuous horizontal red dotted line in the p4v file interface is.
If possible, can you elaborate on the other contents of this dotted line?
I hope to get some interpretation, thank you very much
photoenter image description here

This line is part of an "integration arrow" in Revision Graph.  Click the "Legend" tab (next to the "Navigator" tab) in Revision Graph to see the different types of arrow:

The "tail" of an arrow (which represents the source/donor in an integration) will sometimes include a sort of bracket to indicate which specific revisions were used; I think that's the horizontal line you're referring to here.  In a busy/unfiltered graph with lots of overlapping arrows it can be hard to read, but here's how it looks in a simpler example:

In the above image we can see that #4 of the top file was a "merge w/ edit" from revisions #3 and #4 (specifically) of the bottom file.

So that’s it, I understand, thank you。I did not understand something before
